# Can I put a condition on the lambda expression in the reduce operation?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Can I skip certain operations on the first stream in a lambda expression?
For example

```
List<BeanClass> fetch = getBeanClsss();
BeanClass bean = fetch.stream().reduce(newBean,     (p1,p2)-> { 
p1.setVal(p1.getVal() + p2.getVal());
// if first element skip
// else
p1.setValNum(p1.getValNum() + p2.getValNum());
return p1;
});
```

At first element, I do not want to run p1.setValNum method but p1.setVal method to run. So I want to do everything method except the first one.

Comment: Could you explain *on the first stream*?

Comment: Oh! I forgot to fetch the list.

I want to prevent the first element of this fetch list from performing an operation.

Comment: Could you come up with a normal for loop construction of what your requirement is just to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `reduce` for mutable reduction.  If the stream were ever made parallel, you would get unpredictable results.  You didn't specify the return type of `getVal` and `getValNum`, so I will suppose they both return an `int`.  If you want to clarify your question, I will adjust the answer accordingly.

```
int sumVal = fetch.stream()
                      .mapToInt(BeanClass::getVal)
                      .sum();

int sumValNum = fetch.stream()
                      .skip(1)  // now skipping the first one is straightforward!
                      .mapToInt(BeanClass::getValNum)
                      .sum();

newBean.setVal(newBean.getVal() + sumVal);

newBean.setValNum(newBean.getValNum() + sumValNum);
```

Comment: if the OP uses `reduce`, it means that `newBean.getVal` must always be `zero` (to respect identity), so this would work too : `newBean.setVal(sumVal)`

Comment: I didn't want to make that assumption (although it is a reasonable one to make).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skip()` over [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) as:

```
fetch.stream().skip(1).reduce(newBean,     (p1,p2)-> { 
    ...perform your actions
});
```

> Returns a stream consisting of the remaining elements of this stream
>   after discarding the first n elements of the stream. If this stream
>   contains fewer than n elements then an empty stream will be returned.

Comment: Um... At first element, I do not want to run p1.setValNum method but p1.setVal method to run. So I want to do everything method except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming val and valNum are positive numbers and sum will not overflow*:

Well if I understood correctly, than the very first time you reduce, than this will hold: `p1 == newBean`. In order for the reduce to work correctly you need to respect the `identity property`, what this means that `newBean` has to have `val` and `valNum` set to `zero`.

That means that if you do `p1.getVal()` and see that it's zero, it means that `p2` is actually the first element from your stream.

Also notice that you are violating `reduce` here - you need to return a new instance from the `reduce` method, something like:

```
 .reduce(newBean, (p1, p2) -> {
     BeanClass beanClass = new BeanClass();

     // the first time you reduce
     if(p1.getVal() == 0){
           beanClass.setVal(p1.getVal() + p2.getVal());     
     }else {
           beanClass.setVal(p1.getVal() + p2.getVal());
           beanClass.setValNum(p1.getValNum() + p2.getValNum());
     }
     return beanClass;  
 })
```

Ultimately what you want to do is have a `BeanClass` instance that has `val` being equal to *sum all other val from the Stream, except the first one* and `valNum` being equal to the sum *of all valNum form the Stream*. If so, streaming twice then creating the `instance` is much more simpler with [Misha's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359470/1059372).

Comment: This assumes that `val`s are all positive or all negative.  What if `val` of first element is zero?  or what if the first `val` is `1` and the second one is `-1`.  Simplicity is somewhat subjective, but if the logic that OP is trying to express is that newBean should have `val` that is the sum of all `val`s and `valNum` that is the sum of all `valNum`s except the first, why not just write code that most clearly describes that intent.

Comment: @Misha yes, good points - was a not sure if I should have included them. as far as simplicity goes - this is the reason I added a link to your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not going to execute it in parallel stream(if you do, please be careful with `p1.setValNum(p1.getValNum() + p2.getValNum())`), Here is the solution by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) with fluent setters: The code is explained by itself.

```
StreamEx.of(fetch).mapFirst(b -> newBean.setVal(newBean.getVal() + b.getVal()))
                  .skip(1)
                  .reduce((a, b) -> a.setValNum(a.getValNum() + b.getValNum()));
```

BeanClass with fluent setters:

```
public static class BeanClass {
    private int val;
    private int valNum;
    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }
    public BeanClass setVal(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        return this;
    }
    public int getValNum() {
        return valNum;
    }

    public BeanClass setValNum(int valNum) {
        this.valNum = valNum;
        return this;
    }
    // ...
}
```